# Installing app on market place while its debug flag is set to true

Tags: android, google-play

What are the implications of installing an app in marketplace while its debug flag is set to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What *debug-flag* do you mean?

If you mean the [`android:debuggable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) flag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, then this means, that every person can use a debugger and connect to your aplication via USB. Everybody can breakpoint the application and see which lines of codes are executed when. If imposes a security risk if you do anything what should not be revelead.

If you mean you signed your app with a debug-key, see Rahuls answer, although you can not upload a application without a fully featured release key (this was possible months ago but is blocked by google now)

If you mean you output debug-information via LOG.d(), see Fenders answer.

Comment: I agree that in debug mode user can see all the log messages. But how can they breakpoint the apk. As far as i know you cannot upload app in market place unless it is signed with private key.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you cannot release an application in Android Market signed with a debug key

Check point 3 in this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

debug information is visible in LogCat.

But maybe there is more than this